# trying to make rock paper scissors game using random module,ifelse and pyqt5 and when i execute this program only first condition is executed

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import random


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 433)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(641, 433))
        MainWindow.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 160, 91))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
                                   "image: url(:/newPrefix/donkey kong.jfif);")
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 0, 400, 91))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                   "font: 48pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
                                   "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 0, 160, 91))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                   "font: 48pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
                                   "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 0, 160, 91))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 85, 255);\n"
                                 "image: url(:/newPrefix/OIP.jfif);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 90, 66, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_5)
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 90, 66, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.lcdNumber_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lcdNumber_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lcdNumber_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setObjectName("lcdNumber_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.lcdNumber_2)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 320, 245, 80))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_8)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_8)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("rock.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(65, 47))
        self.pushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.pushButton.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_8)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("paper.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(65, 47))
        self.pushButton_2.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.pushButton_2.setDefault(True)
        self.pushButton_2.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_8)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("scissors.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_3.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButton_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(65, 47))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 140, 221, 169))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("rps.png"))
        self.label_7.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(418, 140, 221, 169))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.label_6.setText("")
        self.label_6.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("rps.png"))
        self.label_6.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showrocklabel_6)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showpaperlabel_6)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.showscissorslabel_6)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "     V"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " S"))

    def random1(self):
        C = random.randint(1, 3)
        print(C)
        L=[self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("rock.png")),self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("paper.png")),self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("scissors.png"))]
        L[C]
        """if C == 1:
                self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("rock.png"))
        if C == 2:
        self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("paper.png"))
        ctrc += 1
        if C == 3:
        self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("scissors.png"))"""

    def showrocklabel_6(self):
        self.label_6.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("rock.png"))
        self.random1()

    def showpaperlabel_6(self):
        self.label_6.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("paper.png"))
        self.random1()

    def showscissorslabel_6(self):
        self.label_6.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("scissors.png"))
        self.random1()


import assets_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i am very new to concept of GUI ,Threads, classes  and objects .Please pardon me

Comment: What's going on in random1?  It looks like nothing but a comment.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: basically when i run this program, it runs on certain cases and crashes on the other,when i was using the if conditions in the triple quote  comment there only "if c==1 " condition was getting executed while when c came 2 or 3 program crashed.

Comment: @AniketGupta 1. please use comments only to reply to other comments, if you need to add further information [edit] the post instead; 2. avoid any greetings, thanks, "please", "I am new", etc, (both in the post and in the comments) as they are unnecessary for the question; 3. your question has nothing to do with threads; 4. the commented code (if we don't consider the wrong indentation) would not crash, so you probably did something else that you changed/removed in the meantime; 5. `setPixmap()` returns `None` so that list is useless; 6. the code above will crash whenever `randint` returns 3 ->

Comment: @AniketGupta -> and that's because the list only has 3 items, and indexes always start from 0; 7. you have not set a main layout, so the window can be resized and the contents will not adapt (nor prevent a minimum size), read how to properly use [layout managers in designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html); 8. you should never, **EVER** manually edit a file generated by pyuic (as written in the warning on top of the file, which you removed and ignored), but only use those files as imports as explained in [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html);